# Find an equation for the tangent line to $f(x)=3x^2-\pi^3$ at $x=4$

Tags: calculus

> Find an equation for the tangent line to $f(x)=3x^2-\pi^3$ at $x=4$

Here is my work so far

$f'(x) = 6x$

$f'(4) = 24$

But if I treat $\pi$ like a variable,

$f'(x) = 6x - 3\pi^3 $

$f'(4) = 24-3\pi^3 $

The answer to this problem is $$ y=24x−48−\pi^3 $$

but I am unsure as to how I should get to this answer. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you need to take $\pi$ as a variable?

Comment: @Saikat I'm not sure that I do, it is just something I tried when I saw that the solution still had pi

Comment: okay. what method do you use to find a tangent line at a point?

Comment: @Saikat I would find the derivative at that point, in other words, f'(4)

Comment: its simply $\frac{x-4}{y-(48-{\pi}^2)}= \frac{1}{24}$

Comment: the gen formula is $\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}=\frac{dy}{dx}(x_1,y_1)$ for the tangent line at $(x_1,y_1)$. okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that an equation of a line with slope $m$ passing by $(x_1,y_1)$ is $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$, here we have
$$x_1=4,\quad y_1=f(x_1)=f(4)=3(4)^2-\pi^3=48-\pi^3\quad\text{ and }\quad m=f'(4)=24$$
It follows that an equation for the tangent line is
$$y-(48-\pi^3)=24(x-4)$$

Which es equivalent to
$$\boxed{\color{blue}{y=24x-48-\pi^3}}$$

Comment: Thanks. I just edited my post, I didn't realize I had made a mistake... pi^2 was supposed to be pi^3. But your answer makes sense all the same.

Comment: @McB: I have edited this too.

Answer (score 1):

As you had correctly determined, the slope of the line is $24$.

Then, simply write

$$y=24x+b$$

where $b$ is the $y$ intercept. To find the intercept we make use of the fact that the tangent line actually touches the curve at $x=4$, $y=3\times 4^2-\pi^2=48-\pi^3$.  Therefore,

$$b=(48-\pi^2)-24(4)=-48-\pi^3$$.

Finally, we have that the equation of the tangent line is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{y=24x-48-\pi^3}$$

Comment: You might want to update your answer; the OP suggested beneath Mario G's solution that he made a typographical mistake in his post.

Comment: Yes, that was my bad. pi^2 should be pi^3. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$f(x)=3x^2-\pi^3\implies f'(x)=6x$$
Hence, $$f'(4)=6(4)=24$$ Now, setting $x=4$ in the given equation $f(x)=3x^2-\pi^3$, we get $$f(4)=3(4)^2-\pi^3=48-\pi^3$$

Hence, the equation of the line is given by point-slope form $$y-(48-\pi^3)=24(x-4)$$
$$\bbox[5pt, border:2.5pt solid #FF0000]{\color{blue}{y=24x-48-\pi^3}}$$